# Grails - Pass JSON/Map object to client

Tags: grails, gsp

I am trying to save a JSON object to a `data-` field in a gsp page.

Mock controller:

```
def test(){
    ['comments': ["1": 1, "3":40 ] ] 
}
```

GSP  (I also tried `(comments as JSON)` )

```
<%@ page import="grails.converters.JSON" %>
<div class='findme' data-comments="${comments as JSON}">
```

Result:

```
<div class='findme' data-comments="{" 1":1,"3":40}">
```

As you can see the quotes are all messed up.  I tried using `encodeAsHTML` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a couple ways to do it.

```
<div class='findme' data-comments="${(new JSON(comments)).toString().encodeAsURL()}">
```

Then I have to pull it out like:

```
JSON.parse(unescape($('.findme').data('comments')))
```

---

Found another way to do it, but it will cause problems if you have anything that has a " in it.  I think encoding it is the way to go.

```
${(comments as JSON).toString().replace("\"", "'")}
```

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I think that you can also do: ${(comments as JSON).encodeAsJavaScript()}

Comment: I have just tried it (in Grails 2.2.3), and indeed you can use ${(comments as JSON).encodeAsJavaScript()} 
This will escape single- and double-quotes with backslashes, so you can use the encoded result inside either single- or double- quoted strings. 
(for example 'comments': ['aa': 11, 'bb':/two "two" o'clock/, 'cc':33]   will be encoded into   "{\"aa\":11,\"bb\":\"two \\\"two\\\" o\'clock\",\"cc\":33}")

Comment: @SorinPostelnic u you should post as an additional answer.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this recently as well and came up with two solutions:

**Solution One**: in the template do this:

```
<div class="comments" data-comments="${comments.encodeAsJSON().encodeAsHTML()}">
```

**Solution Two**: in the controller do this:

```
def test(){
    ['comments': ["1": 1, "3":40 ] as JSON] 
}
```

and in the template do this:

```
<div class="comments" data-comments="${comments.encodeAsHTML()}">
```

I'm using jQuery to do the parsing. With either solution I get the JSON like so:

```
$.parseJSON($('.comments').attr('data-comments'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found an easy way to do that.
First you do:

```
<div class="comments" data-comments="${comments.encodeAsJSON()}">
```

And then in javascript:

```
eval($('.comments').attr('data-comments'));
```